# Semantic role of "the coat" in "the coat lay on the bed"?

Tags: semantics

What is a semantic role of "the coat" in the sentence "the coat lay on the bed"?

Comment: It seems you should be asking in http://ell.stackexchange.com rather than here

Comment: _Patient_. And why don't you consult a book, @mary?

Comment: @JohnLawler Granted, it's just lying there, as if etherized upon a table; but it's not undergoing any action. How is it a Patient?

Comment: @JohnLawler That seems a bit unfair. I know many, many books that run through thematic roles, but don't cover this. Even those books that do are beyond the scope of this site. And Stoney's comment is certainly worthy of a response. C'monn Prof! Mary deserves a bit more of an explanation than that, she's even getting close question votes for having asked the question  -  which is very, very, unfair.

Comment: It seems that two different answers, both with authoritative backing, have been given. Is this a matter of differing terminology or interpretive model? And how on earth can this therefore be general reference?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How can we see the reasons questions have been close-voted for, btw?

Comment: The tag of this question is semantics. Have "semantic roles" anything to do with semantics which is concerned with the meaning of words and their changes in meaning?

Comment: What if "The coat had lain on the bed all day, but now that it was being looked for by its owner, it was nowhere to be found"?

Comment: It's 'off-topic because...
This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.' Any other reason (specified by close-voters) than genref would be – I'd like to think, unthinkable. And genref comes close (though it would have been better for OP to show _some_ research).

Answer (score 5):

An entity which undergoes a change of location or possession, or whose location or possession is specified, is called a **theme**.

See [Jeffrey Gruber, *Studies in Lexical Relations*, Diss. MIT, 1965](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/dm/theses/gruber65.pdf), 47-60.

(By the way, in case this seems an odd choice of term: in Ancient Greek a *thema* was something "put down or placed" ... the modern sense derives from its use in the sense "proposition", something set down for discussion.)

Comment: So V-W snaffled Tallis's theme?

Comment: Well done for having answered the question. And for having recognised that Mary was asking about *thematic roles*. And boo to the close-voters who don't know what thematic roles are!!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, he didn't leave it just lying there on the bed.

Comment: @Araucaria I was reading up on these roles for the first time just this morning, so I knew where to look to confirm my guess. (And I **do** wish we'd stop naming English stuff in Greek and Latin.)

Comment: So it wasn't a bed role.

Comment: @StoneyB Me too! Edwin, aaaaarrrrrgggghhh :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another opinion:

Patient (grammar)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient_%28grammar%29) (tidied):

> In linguistics, a grammatical patient, also called the target or
>   undergoer, is the participant of a situation upon whom an action is
>   carried out. A patient as differentiated from a **theme** must undergo
>   a change in state. A **theme** is denoted by a stative verb, whereas a
>   patient is denoted by a dynamic verb. (At the very least, there is
>   debate to this effect.) Also, patient is the name of the thematic
>   relation with the above definition.
>
> . . .
>
> *The term "**theme**" is often used to describe the same relation as patient.*

It looks like we have the usual confusion of terms.

Comment: [ I've spent today editing rubbish off Wikipedia pages ... I'm just saying. Those pages don't say what they said yesterday! ] But anyhow, I don't understand how the coat in the proposition *the coat lay on the bed* goes under a change of state. What's the change?

Comment: EDIT:
 
Or did you mean *theme*, but intend to give a different explanation from StoneyB? (i.e. his definition would give *patient* in your description, and in most descriptions. But in actual fact *theme* in your definition would be more apt because the situation is actually stative, i.e. there is no change going on) I'd agree with that ...

Comment: I'm saying that Wikipedia here gives several conflicting (in part) definitions here, claiming they're all championed by various schools.

Comment: I don't see any argument for not using 'theme' here and I'd use it. But I'm trying to see why J Lawler opts for 'patient'. In handling the 'change in state' definition, one has to first define 'change in state'. Would 'The coat was thrown into the fire' qualify? 'The metal was treated with acid'?

Comment: Ah, I just got he last line there in your post ... Sorry!

Comment: I'm guessing that John was whizzing though the posts at 1,000 miles per hour?

Comment: Yes, I reckon both of those would qualify :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of confusion over terminology in this area.

One area of confusion is that theta-roles and thematic roles are often conflated, but more confusing is that it seems as though every researcher has their own take on what the roles are and what they are called. Then (as on Wikipedia...) they get listed together without any indication of whether they come for Chomsky or Fillmore or Gruber or Jackendoff or Dowty or Andrews etc. Added to that is the way that quite often the ideas overlap and differ only in detail, where the Devil lives.

If we take Chomsky to be theta-roles (related to verb arguments in a one-argument-one-role relationship), Fillmore/Gruber/Jackendoff to be thematic relations (one NP can have multiple roles), and Dowty and Andrews to be a sort of unified theory (two photo-roles - P-agent and P-patient), then we can reasonably view Jackendoff's list as a standard, based as it is on both Gruber and Fillmore.

One of the common areas of confusion is (Sod's Law strikes here...) PATIENT and THEME, and it is not uncommon to see them lumped together as 'patient/theme'.

PATIENT is reasonably stable as *an entity that undergoes an action* (Jackendoff's description) but THEME is all over the place, being *an entity that has a position assigned to it*, or *an entity that changes position*, or *an entity wit a property assigned to it*. Jackendoff gives us *for verbs of motion: the moving object, for verbs of location; the thing that is located*.

The thing to note here is that it is all about the verb. The verb in our sentence is *lays* which neither locates nor describes motion, so using Jackendoff the thematic role cannot be THEME.

That leaves us with PATIENT which makes sense. What is laying? The coat is.

Note that for thematic or theta roles, things like 'action' and 'affected' need to be seen as more heuristic than material, and we need to avoid distraction by peripheral arguments such as *on the bed*.